# where to show custom info when successfully open a physic machine or connect a remote machine or login a machine in centos 7

Tags: centos, login, tty, getty

**Env**

Centos 7 x64

When I use Teamviewer connect to ttys, I can view infos as below in each Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F6:

```
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64
```

Openning a physic machine, it should also show these messages.

When I log in I can see:

```
Last login: Sun Feb 26 21:54:05 on tty1
```

**Problem**:

Well, Where these info from? where to show these info? Read from a configuration file? Run a script? I did not find any related stuff in /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile.

How do I show my custom infos before login and after login?

Say. The first info which I would like to show is current tty. Is it possible to show this info? how to do that?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Well I now add:

```
echo "$(whoami) now on tt$(fgconsole)"
```

in `~/.bash_profile` to show custom infos after login.

But what about before login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can modify `/etc/motd`, it will print the text contained on every user login.

To change the TTY text which is shown **before** login, you should modify `/etc/issue` or `/etc/issue.net`.

Only for SSH, you can also use `Banner` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to configure custom message for SSH.

Source:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/logon.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)

Comment: issue do works for me. sshd_config seems not work follow [sshd-server-login-banner](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-openssh-sshd-server-login-banner.html)with no-password access? Anyway thanks.